# git lfs migrate with --everything is not migrating all the remote branches

Tags: git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I cloned a repo which has 10+ remote branches and 20+ tags.

Cloned repo has the default branch master checkout.

When I ran git lfs migrate, it migrated all the tags but migrated only master branch, other remote branches were not migrated. Is this the expected behavior? Do I need to checkout all the remote branches before running "git lfs migrate import  --everything --include="*.bin"" ?

LFS version is 3.1.4

Comment: Running into the same issue - only master is migrated, branches are 2500+ ahead and 2500- behind :/

Comment: I am also facing the same issue that only master is migrated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Be sure to use git lfs migrate on a mirror clone.
Use the option --mirror on git clone command.